# Can I switch sound like this?

Tags: audio, switches, potentiometer

As I game on my xbox on the same screen I have connected my pc, sound is a problem as I only have one set of speakers/headset. Please look at my simple design how how Im thinking of solving the problem:

[image]

Im thinking of tuning the volume of the xbox and pc at the same level, say 80% of max and then tune it down with the pot in the diagram.

What you guys think? Would it work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, that should work.  Basically your question seems to be whether you can switch a audio input, and the answer is yes.  There may be a pop at the switchover, but it doesn't sound like that is a issue.

I'll assume the DPDT switch is for switching both channels of a stereo pair.  If so, that's fine.  I just want to point out that since everything is in close proximity presumably operating with the same ground, the grounds don't need to be switched.  Each channel requires only a SPDT switch to select one of two inputs.